# Add tags in Rally C# API ( to userStory or Task)

Tags: c#, rally

I'm struggling with the syntax to update or create a TASK in the Rally REST API with tags.

here is my code:

```
//Tag Holder
ArrayList tagArray = new ArrayList();
tagArray.Add(tag._ref);

//the Task itself
DynamicJsonObject toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();
toCreate["WorkProduct"] = storyRef;

  //i need to pass the tags as a parameter
   NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
  //this is where I am stuck, how do I attach the tags to the parameters

 //call the API to create the task
 CreateResult resultX = api.Create("task", toCreate, parameters );
```

Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collections are a little tricky- you're super close.  Each entry in the array needs to be an object with a _ref property rather than just the ref.

```
DynamicJsonObject tagObj = new DynamicJsonObject();
tagObj["_ref"] = tag._ref;
tagArray.Add(tagObj);
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle, this has been driving me crazy!

Comment: this works great for creating tasks, however when i try to add the tags in an update operation, it says i'm unauthorised (works fine without the tags). See my answer below, the code I am using is identical except for calling update instead of create.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Kyle Morse for giving me the answer to this, in the interest of completeness for anyone else who needs to do this, below is my code for CREATING a task with tags in the Rally API

```
//task object
DynamicJsonObject toCreate = new DynamicJsonObject();    
toCreate["WorkProduct"] = storyRef;

//Tag Holder
ArrayList tagArray = new ArrayList();

//loop through your tags
foreach(tag in tags)
{
     DynamicJsonObject tagObj = new DynamicJsonObject();
     tagObj["_ref"] = tag._ref;
     tagArray.Add(tagObj);
}

//this is where you attach the tags
toCreate["Tags"] = tagArray;  

//call the API to create the task
CreateResult result = api.Create(WorkSpace._ref,"task", toCreate );
```

Comment: Are you using the latest toolkit version (3.2.1)?  There is a timing defect we just uncovered that may be in play here.  Reverting back to version 3.0.1 is the workaround we're recommending for now...  May be worth trying that?